# How to check the result of a PayPal payment executed in .Net?

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am implementing payments with the PayPal .Net SDK. I have reached the "execute" step.

```
var pe = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = payerID };
var pmt = await PayPal.Api.Payment.ExecuteAsync(apiContext, paymentId, pe);
```

However, I cannot find how to know the payment state?

Is summing the values of the following the only method ?

```
pmt.transactions[i].related_resources[j].sale.amount
```

**UPDATE**

This is how I do it for now (any suggestion for improvement is welcome):

```
var pmt = await PayPal.Api.Payment.ExecuteAsync(apiContext, paymentId, pe);

if (pmt.state == STATE_CREATED)
    throw new PayPalExecuteException() { Error = PayPalExecuteException.PayPalExecuteErrors.Pending };
if (pmt.state == STATE_FAILED)
    throw new PayPalExecuteException() { Error = PayPalExecuteException.PayPalExecuteErrors.Failed };

decimal totalAmount = 0;
decimal fees = 0;
string amountCurrency = "";
string feesCurrency = "";
foreach(var trans in pmt.transactions)
{
    foreach(var ress in trans.related_resources)
    {
        if (ress.sale.state == STATE_COMPLETED)
        {
            totalAmount += decimal.Parse(ress.sale.amount.total, CultureEnUs);
            fees += decimal.Parse(ress.sale.transaction_fee.value, CultureEnUs);
            amountCurrency = ress.sale.amount.currency;
            feesCurrency = ress.sale.transaction_fee.currency;
        }
    }
}
```

I use this method as I don't know if a payment can have several transactions for the same sale: for example if the sale is $100, the person has $50 on its account, this customer will pay half from his account and half from his credit card, what is PayPal response in such case?